# Ao clicar no botão recebo uma mensagem de "ReferenceError"

Tags: javascript, react, front-end

### Contexto

Criei uma aplicação que apresenta uma listagem feita a partir da variável - está no estado da aplicação - `projects` juntamente com um botão "Botão adicionar".

Ao clicar nele estou recebendo a mensagem `App.js:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: project is not defined`.

Abaixo colocarei a mensagem de erro recebida e depois o código de minha aplicação.

#### Mensagem de erro

```
App.js:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: project is not defined
    at handleAddProject (App.js:37)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:8508)

Uncaught ReferenceError: project is not defined
    at handleAddProject (App.js:37)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:8508)
```

#### Código da aplicação

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';


function App() {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState(['Desenvolvimento de app', 'Front-end web']);
    

    function handleAddProject() {
        setProjects([ ...project, `Novo projeto ${Date.now()}` ]);
        console.log(projects);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Header title="Projects" />

            <ul>
                {projects.map(project => <li key={project}>{project}</li>)}
            </ul>

            <button type="button" onClick={handleAddProject}>Botão Adicionar</button>

        </>
    );
};
```

#### Print do erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `setProjects([ ...project, 'Novo projeto ${Date.now()}' ]);` voce colocou `...project`, acredito que deveria ser `...projects`.

Comment: Recomendo sempre o uso de um lint, como o `eslint-config-pagarme-base` ou `eslint-airbnb`. Eles evitam esses problemas de variável não declarada e outros tipos de problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro indica que a referência `project` não está definido, isso pode ocorrer quando se tenta chamar uma referência que ainda não foi declarada no programa, ou quando ocorreu algum erro de digitação.

Você está declarando uma variável de state chamada "projects"  e não "project", será que não se confundiu no momento de digitar? Especificamente no trecho:

```
function handleAddProject() {
        setProjects([ ...project, `Novo projeto ${Date.now()}` ]);
        console.log(projects);
    };
```

Comment: Deu certo. Grato